# My Magento 2.1.5 is missing PayPal All-In-One Payment Solutions

Tags: magento2, paypal, paypal-payments-pro, paypal-pro

Not sure why, but I dont have PayPal All-In-One Payment Solutions. All I have as options for paypal are PayPal Express Checkout & Braintree. Not sure what to do or how to get it. Any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look under "Braintree" all the way to the right.  There should be some blue text saying "Other Paypal Payment Solutions".  Click that to expand a section where you'll see all the other PayPal solutions.  See my screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow! I thought I checked every link on that page. Have no idea how I missed that! Thanks @Brett

Comment: I missed it too... had to find this answer :D

Comment: Now what to do when the other paypal solutions arent showing, the link is there but no options are rendered, somehow it got broken for no obvious reason.

Comment: @siux I would check that you don't have a JavaScript error causing an issue in the admin. I haven't run into that issue, so it's just a shot in the dark.

Comment: @Brett sadly it wasn't a technical issue, but a mage2 support issue, the payment methods aren't supported in the shop origin country: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-countries.html